# what is standalone application?

Tags: c#, .net

Context is C#,.Net framework.
Is it the application that runs without any need to install framework?
Or is it just a desktop(windows) application?

Comment: Standalone in Firefox means two version on same system. sometime it's called for no required [portable]. i  not know what it means in c#.

Comment: @Ian Moss: Then don't say anything. You're only going to confuse the OP with your comment.

Comment: May be you tell about SilverLight application?

Comment: @acoolaum,it is not related to silverlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it the application that runs without any need to install framework?

No. Any C# application is going to require the CLR to be installed.

> Or is it just a desktop(windows) application?

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, .net applications are compiled not into the native binaries that are ready to run under target OS, but into *Intermediate Language* that is compiled into native executable in the memory, right after and each time you run an application.

Answer (score 0):

To me, a *standalone* application is one that doesn't need an installer. It is just an EXE that you can copy to a folder and double-click on to run.

Comment: Depends on the installer. Something like ClickOnce certainly behaves as standalone, but it does install things.